# Resize the EditText when softkeyboard gets displayed

Tags: android, android-layout

How to resize the EditText when the softkeyboard gets displayed? For compatibility reasons(different screen sizes and densities), can we resize the EditText to a value such that it is "20dp" above the softkeyboard or the whole screen becomes scrollable? Read many posts on SE about using  nut they didn't work for me.

The main.xml file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.04" >
  <Button
            android:id="@+id/Save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/SaveButton" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/NoteTextBox"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Save"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="false" >

            <requestFocus />

        </EditText>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` it may help your.
More about `imeOptions` you can read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions)

Hope it helps

Comment: so look [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) i hope it will help you.